# allow SSH to subdomain on Plesk 17

Tags: ssh, plesk, plesk-onyx

I would like to allow SSH access to a user on Plesk 17.

I have looked at the following link;

https://support.plesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/213370009-How-to-give-Plesk-domain-users-SSH-access-to-domain-s-DocumentRoot

However, I have the following problems;

1. when I navigate to Domains > MyDomain > Web Hosting Access. I don't have the option to allow SSH
2. The default username associated with this domain will allow access to all domains, is it possible to restrict SSH access to a single subdomain (as you can with an FTP account).

Answer (score 1):

Plesk creates one system user for each subscription. It the subdomain belongs to the subscription, it is not possible SSH access exclusively for this subdomain.

Instead of creating a subdomain for existing `example.com` subscription, you can create subscription named `subdomain.example.com`. It will have a separate system user, virtual host directory and SSH access settings.

[image]

Comment: I followed this per the link I gave. Th issue is I dont get the 'Access to server over SSH dropdown?